# show that the set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Suppose $f$ is a reimann integrable function on [a,b]. Let V={$x\in[a,b]$ : $\int\limits_{x}^{b} f(t)dt$ is continuous}.Then show that V is compact

Clearly V is bounded.So we only have to prove that V is closed.For that I take a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in V which converges to x.How to prove that x is in V

Comment: The definition of $V$ does not make sense.

Comment: This question seems fine for me, I don't know why it was downvotes. I demand downvoter to comeback and write its reason for downvote. also I demand downvoter to pay attention to this question and remove their downvote if an edit is made

Answer (score 1):

We can prove a stronger result, namely that $V=[a,b]$. I will do this without using sequences.

It was given that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, so for all $x\in[a,b]$, $\int_{x}^{b}f(t)dt$ exists.

We will now prove that the function $F(x)=\int_{x}^{b}f(t)dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Given an arbitrary $c\in[a,b]$, notice that $F(c)-F(x)=\int_{c}^{b}f(t)dt-\int_{x}^{b}f(t)dt=\int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt$ holds for all $x\in[a,b]$. It was assumed that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, so it must be bounded there, that is $m\leq f(t)\leq M$ for some $m,M\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Basic integral inequalities then establish that

$$m(x-c)\leq \int_{c}^{x}f(t)dt\leq M(x-c)$$

so $m(x-c)\leq F(c)-F(x)\leq M(x-c)$. If $a<c<b$, then as $x\to c$, both $m(x-c)$ and $M(x-c)$ approach $0$, so the squeeze theorem gives

$$\lim_{x\to c}[F(c)-F(x)]=0$$

which implies that $\lim_{x\to c}F(x)=F(c)$. This shows that $F$ is continuous on $(a,b)$. If $c=a$ or $c=b$, a similar argument applies with right-hand and left-hand limits, respectively. It follows that $F(x)=\int_{x}^{b}f(t)dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Thus, $V=[a,b]$.